# Datagridview - multi column combobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need multi column combobox in datagrid, to display 2 table values from my DB, separated by line in combobox. I've allready done this using normal combobox with Enter and Draw_Item event, and now I'm trying to do this in datagrid too - in Cell_Enter and Cell_Painting events. Problem occurs when I try to set DataViewrow - I get error "Index is not a member of DatagridView...". Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub MyDGV_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MyDGV.CellEnter
        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

            Dim SQL As String = "SELECT Field1,Field2 from MyTable"
            Dim dtb As New DataTable()
            dtb.Columns.Add("Field1", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
            dtb.Columns.Add("Field2", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

            Try
               Myconn() 'My connection to Oracle
               Using dad As New OracleDataAdapter(SQL, Myconn)
                    dad.Fill(dtb)
               End Using
               Column1.DisplayMember = "Field1"
               Column1.DataSource = dtb

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Finally
                Myconn.Close()
            End Try
        End If

 End Sub

    Private Sub MyDGV_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles MyDGV.CellPainting

        If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then

           Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(Column1.Items(e.Index), DataRowView) 'I have error here - this line should get value of each row   

           Dim id As String = drv("Field1").ToString()
           Dim name As String = drv("Field2").ToString()

           Dim r1 As Rectangle = e.CellBounds
           r1.Width = r1.Width / 2

           Using sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(MyDGV.BackColor)
               e.Graphics.DrawString(id, e.CellStyle.Font, sb, r1)
           End Using

           Using p As Pen = New Pen(Color.AliceBlue)
               e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, r1.Right, 0, r1.Right, r1.Bottom)
           End Using

           Dim r2 As Rectangle = e.CellBounds
           r2.X = e.CellBounds.Width / 2
           r2.Width = r2.Width / 2

           Using sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(MyDGV.BackColor)
               e.Graphics.DrawString(name, e.CellStyle.Font, sb, r2)
           End Using

        End If

    End Sub
```

Any help much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the members of the [DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellpaintingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).  I would try leveraging the RowIndex property:

```
Dim drv As DataGridViewRow = CType(MyDGV.Rows(e.RowIndex), DataGridViewRow)
```

Then you may need to get the values you need by referencing the cells property:

```
Dim id As String = drv.Cells("Field1").Value.ToString()
Dim name As String = drv.Cells("Field2").Value.ToString()
```

Comment: I actually tried this before posting here. It's not working - "Value of type DataGridViewRow cannot be converted to DataRowView" error.

Comment: @No alias, now I get error: "Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection". I thins DatagridViewCellPaintingEventArgs occurs before combobox is being populated. Can I change this ?...I tried changing Cell_Enter code to Form_Load, but still same.